# FFmpeg command line running in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-ffmpeg

I am developing an application to convert videos (mp4) to (mp3). I am using this library to the conversion but the process is too slow. https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues

I already tried with a special command but the library has problems. There are many people complaining about that.

They compile the FFmpeg and created a library for android.

I already compile FFmpeg with NDK to be used in android follow this links:

http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

https://blog.sonnguyen.org/2016/07/08/Build-ffmpeg-with-Android-NDK-r12/

I want to know how can I use those files in my android project. I read about JNI but I don't have any idea how to start or what to do

I just want to use this command line from FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 out.mp3
```

If someone can help me I will be so glad.  Thanks

Comment: why you are writing out.mp3.avi?

Comment: It can be just out.mp3

Comment: @LalitJadav sorry was s mistake when I was writting here